# Is there a way of constraining a generic type to be a member of a set of types?

Tags: generics, f#

I have the following record

```
type RecordPath<'a,'b> = {
    Get: 'a -> 'b
    Path:string
}
```

I want to constrain `'b` to be a member of the set of types that can naturally be represented in a relational database column (`int`; `string`; `DateTime`; etc).

I could use a class instead of a record with a private constructor and some static creator methods that only cater for the types I care about. But I was wondering if there is a way to do this with a record.

I also considered extending the types I want to allow with something like this

```
type String with static member CanBeUsedInRecordPath = true
```

And then use SRTPs for all functions that operate on a `RecordPath`, but then it is technically possible (although unlikely) for someone to decide to extend some type I don't want to support with that extension method.

So is a class with a private constructor the only way to do this in F#?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following seems to satisfy my requirements.

```
module RecordPath =
    type RecordPath<'a, 'b> = private {
        Get: 'a -> 'b
        Path:string
    }
    with 
        static member Create (f: 'a -> string) = {Get = f; Path = "not important for this demo"}
        static member Create (f: 'a -> int) = {Get = f; Path = "not important for this demo"}
        static member Create (f: 'a -> DateTime) = {Get = f; Path = "not important for this demo"}
```

I'll wait a bit before accepting this as the answer in case someone comes up with a better way.

Comment: This is exactly what I was going to suggest after seeing your question and before seeing your answer :-). I think this is probably the best approach.

Comment: I have a similar scenario where I have done exactly the same thing.